# pandas. How to update a new pandas column row by row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to add a new column in a pandas data frame, then update the value of the column row by row:

```
    my_df['col_A'] = 0
    for index, row in my_df.iterrows():

        my_df.loc[index]['col_A'] = 100 # value here changes in real case
        print(my_df.loc[index]['col_A'])

    my_df
```

However, in the print out, all values in the col_A are still 0, why is that? What did I miss? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are assigning to a slice in this line `my_df.loc[index]['col_A'] = 100`

Instead do

```
my_df['col_A'] = 0
for index, row in my_df.iterrows():

    my_df.loc[index, 'col_A'] = 100 # value here changes in real case
    print(my_df.loc[index]['col_A'])
```